# bash: output \n \t characters from mysql query

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, format

I currently have

```
$ echo "`echo "use joomla; describe jos_content" | mysql --batch -u root -ppassword`"
```

and I would expect output that starts like this

```
Field\tType\tNull\tKey\tDefault\tExtra\n
```

but instead I get

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
```

I have tried all sorts of items at the moment. I could use mysql --html and sed, but, I would only like to go there if this doesn't work out.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is the right tool for this job, not `echo`.

```
echo "use joomla; describe jos_content" | mysql --batch -u root -ppassword \
       | sed 's/\t/\\t/g; s/$/\\n/'
```

---

Or if you really want all of the output on one line:

```
echo "use joomla; describe jos_content" | mysql --batch -u root -ppassword \
       | sed 's/\t/\\\\t/g' | while read line ; do echo -n $line\\n ; done
```

(note the quadruple escape in the `sed` call).

Comment: this worked great. I was hoping for something a bit more efficient. But oh well. I've put too much time into this already.

Thank you for helping me on my way.

Comment: oh, also, what is up with the quadrapole escape!? hehe (I'm curious)

Comment: ah, after looking at the escapes I can make more sense of it. Thanks again.

Comment: @bonfire, `sed` interprets `\\\\t` as `\\t`.  Then, `read` interprets `\\t` as `\t`.

Comment: I'd say `awk` is the right tool, because this is tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the outer echo:

```
echo "use joomla; describe jos_content" | mysql --batch -u root -ppassword
```

`echo`ing the output causes all the spaces to be collapsed.

EDIT: MySQL does not output the escaped characters you want (e.g. literal \ then t).  In bash (you must use bash's printf), you can get an approximation with:

```
printf '%q' "$(echo 'use mysql; describe user;'|mysql --batch -u root '-ppassword')"
```

That will output starting with:

```
$'Field\tType\tNull\tKey\tDefault\tExtra\n
```

This is quoting the characters for use with a shell.  You can also use sed, as discussed.

Comment: thank you, but that does not display the special characters =/

Comment: after the edit there is still some stuff intertwined with the the output. But, I appreciated the responses and taught me about printf.

Next time I have a similar issue I will have to look into printf.

Thank you again.